# Format number by billions thousand hundreds

Tags: javascript

What is the way to format a number

`12345678`

to format

```
<span>12</span>
<span>345</span>
<span>678</span>
```

with Javascript?

Comment: what is the ultimate goal to do with the numbers?

Comment: Post the code you tried that isn't working.

Comment: I need to get hundreds thousand billions separated... To be able to use it in my countdown plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click <kbd>Run code snippet...</kbd> to see the result

```js
function numberToHtml(n) {
  function createSpan(n) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = n;
    return span;
  }
  function iter(n, container) {
    if (n === '') return container;
    container.insertBefore(createSpan(n.slice(-3)), container.firstChild);
    return iter(n.slice(0,-3), container);
  }
  return iter(String(n), document.createDocumentFragment());
}

document.body.appendChild(numberToHtml(12345678));
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Is there an easy way to add some symbol after the `last` iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You can add commas at every 000 like this:

```
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
  while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
  val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
  }
  return val;
  }
```

And then call this function like so:

```
var orig_number = 12345678;
var formatted_number = commaSeparateNumber(orig_number);
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.number').keyup(function(event) {
  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
  return value
  .replace(/\D/g, '')
  .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
  ;
  });
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A series of division/modulus should get you the pieces.

For example:

```
var x = 12345678;
var hund = parseInt(x / 1      ) % 1000; // 678
var thou = parseInt(x / 1000   ) % 1000; // 345
var mill = parseInt(x / 1000000) % 1000; // 12
```

You could generalize and loop checking for when the result gets to 0.